# Using a lot of static analysis tools in one application

Tags: java, sonarqube, code-analysis, findbugs, pmd

Now, we have a lot of tool for static code analysis in java.

For example:

- PMD
- CPD
- FindBugs
- CheckStyle
- Sonar
- JDepend

etc.

Is it good to use all these tools in one application (using maven we will fail the build in case of negative scenarios). Are they interchangeable or they check approximately the same? Or it will be just excess?
Maybe there are some categories for these tools?

Comment: While they help the developer to some extent, most of these reports are for *showing off* to project managers and clients.

Comment: Why would you use all of them if Sonar contains PMD, Checkstyle and FindBugs ?

Comment: I'm not going to use all off them, I just want to see the difference. As I understand the best way to use just sonar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of Sonar is to agregate results from all the core analysis engines (like PMD, Findbugs, Checkstyle), so that's why Sonar embeds all those tools, plus many more.

So my advice would be to set up a continuous inspection server based on Sonar, and don't worry about any other tool as you'll get the best of all of them with Sonar.

You can read the following blog entry about continuous inspection: http://www.sonarsource.org/continuous-inspection-practice-emerges-with-sonar/

Answer (score 1):

I use only FindBugs - greate tool. Realy helps to define problem/potential problem places.

But some times you have code that should be implemented in way that FindBugs gives redudant error/warning. Think it can be suppressed with some annotations.

But you never replace good code review with this tools.

Comment: +1 It can be suppressed with FindBugs `@SuppressWarnings` annotation. The argument is the unique string identifier you can see when you look at the bug details. It is a bit annoying that the annotation name is the same like java.lang.SuppressWarnings. So you have to use full qualified one of these when both are used in the same class.

Answer (score 1):

They are not interchangable but you don't need them all in the same application.

Categories:

1. Reporting - Sonar provides a nice visual dashboard of the other tools you are using (plus JUnit, etc)
2. Static analysis - PMD, FindBugs, CheckStyle
3. Duplicate code - CPD
4. Design/package dependencies - JDepend

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the set of rules you want to enforce. Using another tool makes only sense if it provides additional checks. Another problem is that you have to configure all tools in a way that they don't check with rules that are contradictory to each other. And finally, you will get lots of redundant warnings.
Conclusion: Try to find a minimum set of tools that provide all checks you need.

Answer (score 0):

In [qulice.com](http://www.qulice.com/index.html) (a composite static analysis tool for Maven projects) we use Checkstyle, PMD, FindBugs, and a few our custom rules. Somewhere they were conflicting between each other and we had to resolve that conflicts by disabling certain rules in one of them. Besides that, these three open source static analyzers live together and enforce the most important (and simple) design principles.